# Java Spring Boot - Change the Port of Actuator Health Endpoint to a Custom Port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Java Spring Boot Application, which is currently running on http://localhost:8080. I will be containerising this application to be deployed in Kubernetes. For this I have enabled the `actuator health` endpoint by adding the following to the `pom.xml` file.

```
<!-- Spring boot actuator to expose metrics endpoint -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, the application Health Endpoint works successfully on http://localhost:8080/actuator/health endpoint. I wish to change the PORT of the **Health Endpoint URL to be 8081**. *(This is to ensure that I can expose 8080 port to the public and expose 8081 port only to the load balancer. This is a personal preference)*

How can I change the port of the **Health Endpoint** so that the health endpoint URL becomes http://localhost:8081/actuator/health, and the application runs on http://localhost:8080/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, actuator will be accessible using the default http port configured (commonly 8080).

Actuator has a number of configuration properties you can configure that fall under the `management.` prefix. You can specifically set the `management.port` in `application.properties` to have actuator endpoints to be served on the custom port:

In `application.properties`, set:

```
management.port=8081
```

For more details, check section 48.2 of the [Spring Boot - Production Ready Monitoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) documentation.

Comment: It appears that in newer versions of Spring Boot (5+), the config option is `management.server.port`

Comment: @GreenGiant - Spring (not Spring Boot)

Answer (score 21):

As pointed out by GreenGiant, the Spring Boot 5+ way of doing this is through:

```
management.server.port
```

Comment: is `springboot5+` == `springboot1.5+`?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the bellow 2 steps you can have 8081 private and 8080 as public.

**Step 1:**

Change your application server port to 8081 first. That means in your localhost it will run on 8081.

http://localhost:8081/actuator/health

http://localhost:8081/

```
To do that, in your application.properties file, add server.port=8081
```

**Step 2:**

However, when deployed in Kubernetes, 8081 port will be the private port.

In Kubernetes, expose 8080 port to the public.

Add a route that maps 8080 to your application 8081 port.