# Spring Boot Actuator for Spring MVC without Spring boot on another port

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot-actuator

I want to set up the spring boot actuator for the spring MVC. And everything seems to be fine, but I need to output the actuator on a different port, which I can't do. Maybe someone came across this?

Dependencies:

```
 org.springframework:spring-webmvc: 4.3.9.RELEASE

 group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-actuator', version: '1.5.4.RELEASE'

 group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.15
```

Configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ManagementContextConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

.

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class ActuatorConfig {

    private final int SERVER_PORT = 9091;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("/actuator", SERVER_PORT);
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties() {
        ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties = new ManagementServerProperties();
        managementServerProperties.setPort(SERVER_PORT);
        return managementServerProperties;
    }
}
```

This code displays metrics, but i can not run metrics on another port.I also suspect this is due to the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class`, but I do not quite understand how to configure it and get the server to start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Spring Boot - Change the Port of Actuator Health Endpoint to a Custom Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685392/java-spring-boot-change-the-port-of-actuator-health-endpoint-to-a-custom-port)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz If I don't use spring boot, can this help? If yes, can you tell me how to help spring find application.properties. In any case, thanks for the answer.

Comment: _"I don't use spring boot"_: what do you mean by that (many classes and annotations in your code are from Spring Boot)? Does it mean you use an external Tomcat to deploy the application or do you have a custom class to start it?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, I am using spring boot dependencies, but when adding application.propertis, nothing has changed

Comment: But started getting an exception. `WARN  EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:159 - Could not start embedded management container on different port (management endpoints are still available through JMX)`

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to your application.properties file,

```
management.port=your_port  //eg: 8085
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can this help if I don't use spring boot?